# How do I find an installed nuget package at the console?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have tried

```
Get-Package -filter json
```

But this shows `No packages installed.`
I want to find packages containing "json" not starting with  "json" is this possible?

The GUI package manager search works how I want, but how do I do this on the console?

Comment: You might want to open an issue at http://github.com/nuget/home for this. I tried this in VS 2015 Update 2 as well. If I search for NewtonSoft, I'm able to get the package but not if i search for json, was not able to test on a previous version to see if it was a regression. Either way open an issue and we will take a look at it.

Comment: added: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. The [code](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/release-3.5.0-beta2/src/NuGet.Clients/PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets/NuGetPowerShellBaseCommand.cs#L547) specifically looks for `StartWith`.

```
        foreach (var project in projects)
        {
            var packageRefs = await project.GetInstalledPackagesAsync(token);
            // Filter the results by string
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
            {
                packageRefs = packageRefs.Where(p => p.PackageIdentity.Id.StartsWith(filter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            }

            ...
```

Since scripts rely on these cmdlets behavior, we can't just change it to `IndexOf` or something like that because that would be a breaking change.

We will take a look at the issue you opened and come up with a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the `-Filter` parameter is applied when you use `-ListAvailable`, which goes to the remote repositories instead of searching specifically in the project.

You can still use `Get-Package` in a similar fashion you posted in your question, though:

```
Get-Package | Where-Object { $_.Id -like '*json*' }
```